# How to create third sheet that merge data from two sheets that have a common column with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, merge

Every month I need to create a report based on two others. I upload the two reports to Drive and I can obtain their values in two arrays, according to the code below:

```
function mergeReports() {
 
  var report1_ID = "1keGWvdMoNLPR1S2n_66QOyy-c3euZs0HOcn9qLLt9L8";
  var report2_ID = "1HpDkgpXHTY5aI7uKkcY5a6ZEQ--T860aGaRhlwhRT0P";

  var report1_page = "report1";
  var report2_page = "report2";

  var report1_range = "A6:D";
  var report2_range = "A6:D";

  var report1_values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(report1_ID).getSheetByName(report1_page).getRange(report1_range).getValues();
  var report2_values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(report2_ID).getSheetByName(report2_page).getRange(report2_range).getValues();

  var report1 = report1_values.filter(function(r){
    return r.join("").length>0;
  });

  var report2 = report2_values.filter(function(r){
    return r.join("").length>0;
  });

  Logger.log(report1);
  Logger.log(report2);

}
```

Here is the Report 1:

| HOUSE | SUBTYPE | ORDER | REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOUSE1 | SUBT1 | 1 | 1 |
| HOUSE2 | SUBT2 | 2 | 1 |
| HOUSE3 | SUBT3 | 3 | 1 |
| HOUSE4 | SUBT4 | 4 | 1 |

Here is the Report 2:

| TYPE | SUBTYPE | ORDER | REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TYPE1 | SUBT1 | 1 | 1 |
| TYPE2 | SUBT2 | 2 | 1 |
| TYPE2 | SUBT3 | 3 | 1 |
| TYPE3 | SUBT5 | 5 | 1 |
| TYPE4 | SUBT6 | 6 | 1 |

What I would like is to generate a Report 3 that merges these through a common column (ORDER), as below:

| ORDER | TYPE | SUBTYPE | HOUSE | REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TYPE1 | SUBT1 | HOUSE1 | 1 |
| 2 | TYPE2 | SUBT2 | HOUSE2 | 1 |
| 3 | TYPE2 | SUBT3 | HOUSE3 | 1 |
| 4 |  | SUBT4 | HOUSE4 | 1 |
| 5 | TYPE3 | SUBT5 |  | 1 |
| 6 | TYPE4 | SUBT6 |  | 1 |

Your help will be appreciated and valuable in developing my skills using GAS.

I researched several topics, but they didn't quite match what I was looking for, so I couldn't figure out how to be successful.

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between `var report1_range = "A6:D";`, `var report2_range = "A6:D";` and your showing tables? For example, the values of "HOUSE1" and "TYPE1" in your showing tables are "A6" instead of "A2"? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The 2 reports are extracted from the same database and have the ORDER field as the main key. However, I don't know why, it doesn't display all the information for the same order in just one report. Order 1, for example, has values such as HOUSE1 and TYPE1, but not in the same report. That's why I need to unify the 2 reports using the ORDER field.

The fact that the range is A6:D is because in the 2 original reports there is an irrelevant header and the data only starts on line 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1"];
  const dObj = { pA: [] };
  shts.forEach((n) => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    let col = {};
    let idx = {};
    hs.forEach((h, i) => { col[h] = i + 1; idx[h] = i; });
    vs.forEach((r) => {
      let p = r[idx["ORDER"]];
      if (!dObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        dObj[p] = [{ ORDER: "", TYPE: "", SUBTYPE: "", HOUSE: "", REQUESTS: "" }];
        ["ORDER", "TYPE", "SUBTYPE", "HOUSE", "REQUESTS"].forEach(e => {
          if (~hs.flat().indexOf(e)) {
            dObj[p][e] = r[idx[e]]
          } else {{
            dObj[p][e] = "";
          }}
        });
        dObj.pA.push(p);
      } else {
         ["ORDER", "TYPE", "SUBTYPE", "HOUSE", "REQUESTS"].forEach(e => {
          if (~hs.flat().indexOf(e) && !dObj[p][e]) {
            dObj[p][e] = r[idx[e]]
          }
        });       
      }
    });
  });
  let o = dObj.pA.sort((a,b)=> a - b).map((p,i) => {
    return [dObj[p].ORDER,dObj[p].TYPE,dObj[p].SUBTYPE,dObj[p].HOUSE,dObj[p].REQUESTS]
  });
  o.unshift(["ORDER", "TYPE", "SUBTYPE", "HOUSE", "REQUESTS"]);
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Sheet0:

| HOUSE | SUBTYPE | ORDER | REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOUSE1 | SUBT1 | 1 | 1 |
| HOUSE2 | SUBT2 | 2 | 1 |
| HOUSE3 | SUBT3 | 3 | 1 |
| HOUSE4 | SUBT4 | 4 | 1 |

Sheet1:

| TYPE | SUBTYPE | ORDER | REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TYPE1 | SUBT1 | 1 | 1 |
| TYPE2 | SUBT2 | 2 | 1 |
| TYPE2 | SUBT3 | 3 | 1 |
| TYPE3 | SUBT5 | 5 | 1 |
| TYPE4 | SUBT6 | 6 | 1 |

Sheet2:

| ORDER | TYPE | SUBTYPE | HOUSE | REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TYPE1 | SUBT1 | HOUSE1 | 1 |
| 2 | TYPE2 | SUBT2 | HOUSE2 | 1 |
| 3 | TYPE2 | SUBT3 | HOUSE3 | 1 |
| 4 |  | SUBT4 | HOUSE4 | 1 |
| 5 | TYPE3 | SUBT5 |  | 1 |
| 6 | TYPE4 | SUBT6 |  | 1 |

Comment: Impressive! It worked magically and perfectly. Now I'm studying line by line for better understanding. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a very useful technique for reorganizing data.  In textbooks it falls under the category of pivot tables.